# Creating C++ Soap Client in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, soap

I am trying to connect to a Soap Web service. I am very familiar with C++ , but this is the first time I try anything related to the web. I would like to use visual studio. Can anyone explain how to do it?

Comment: [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html).

Comment: what is your question exactly? This kind of questions can be answered by 5 minutes googling.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain how to do it?

Some notes (this is not a complete list/howto, but more of a guideline):

First, you need to choose a SOAP client library for C++. The best out there (or not the best - that's debatable) seems to be gSOAP.

For gSOAP (the library I am familiar with):

Second, (with gSOAP) you can generate a code base particular to the SOAP endpoints you need to connect with.

Third, add a project in Visual Studio ("project A") that links against this generated code, and hides it's interface behind it's own (A's) interface. This is not mandatory, but it is good practice, ensuring that changes to the generated code, do not force you to recompile your entire code base.

**DO NOT EDIT** the generated code. That would ensure you can no longer regenerate it, or that when you regenerate it you will have to apply all your edits again. If you have any workaround or processing to be done on requests/responses, implement those in Project A.

Then, write your code based on your Project A.